# Number of groups of Lie Type of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

As a combined math/programming exercise, I want to make a function that takes in a natural number $n$ and returns the number of simple groups of order $n$. From the classification of simple finite groups, every simple finite group is cyclic, alternating, Lie type or sporadic.

So far,

1. Cyclic is straightforward, since there always is one cyclic group of order $n$.
2. Alternating is straightforward, since there is one alternating group of order n if $n=m!/2$ for some $m$, and $0$ otherwise.
3. Since there are just $26$ sporadic groups, I can do them case by case. The main challenge of these will be storing the size of the monster as an integer.

But how many are there of Lie type of order $n$? Is there a straightforward formula for calculating this?

As a bonus, if I successfully create this function (takes in $n$ and returns the number of **simple groups** of order $n$) how could I extend it to a function that takes in a number $n$ and returns the number of **groups** of order $n$?

Comment: Each type has a corresponding formula for the group of that type of a certain degree. Presumably you could get estimates on these formulas, then brute force check the formula when it takes values near $n$ to see where it crosses over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orders of the groups of Lie type are polynomials in the size of the underlying field with the degree depending on the rank. You can find formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups

So you could calculate through all series and check which once come up for a given order.
Since there are quite a few series, it will be a bit of a slog to go through all cases. Be aware that the group orders are not monotonous in the field order, e.g. $L_2(128)$ is larger than $L_2(157)$.

You might want to check/compare your results with:
[http://www.madore.org/~david/math/simplegroups.html](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/simplegroups.html)

Answer (score 3):

> As a bonus, if I successfully create this function (takes in n and returns the number of **simple groups** of order $n$) how could I extend it to a function that takes in a number $n$ and returns the number of **groups** of order $n$?

This is hopeless, we don't know a simple way to calculate the number of groups of order $n$ even if $n$ is a prime power (in which case the only simple factors are cyclic). It would require you to solve the group extension problem which is quite hard.

To give a concrete example, it's currently not known how many groups there are of order $2^{11}=2048$.

Comment: Good to know. Out of curiosity, for say, the groups of order up to 100, we do know the number of groups of each order. Could these be calculated from the corresponding numbers of simple groups, or would this also be a hard problem?

Comment: @ChristianDoucette it's true that every finite group has a Jordan-Hölder series, but it's non-trivial to compute how many groups you can build out of a given list of finite simple groups. Of course, knowing the simple factors is a first step if you want to classify groups of a certain order, but you still need to put in some work beyond that.

Comment: There are, e.g.,  267 groups of order 128 and 2328 of order 128. All of them only involve one simple group, the one of order 2. There are algorithms that can be used to enumerate groups of a give order (e.g. https://www.quendi.de/data/papers/EHH2018-small-groups.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.02933.pdf) but the algorithms required, even if you want to get only up to order 64, probably require several man-years of implementation time.